# Process subject line of each emails from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Currently I'm trying to process the subject line of each e-mail received from outlook. All of the subject lines have been listed on column F. I want display all the subject lines of the e-mails (duplicates will be removed and only one line will be kept for the each conversation - mails with RE or FW have been stripped away of these). A new worksheet will contain all of the subject lines from inbox (taken just once after the duplicates were removed).

Code:

```
For Each oItem In objSourceFolder.Items

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("A" & contor).Value = oItem.SentOn
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("B" & contor).Value = oItem.CreationTime
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("C" & contor).Value = oItem.ReceivedTime
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("D" & contor).Value = oItem.SenderName
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("E" & contor).Value = oItem.SenderEmailAddress
    If (Left(oItem.Subject, 4) = "FW: ") Or (Left(oItem.Subject, 4) = "Fw: ") Or (Left(oItem.Subject, 4) = "RE: ") Or (Left(oItem.Subject, 4) = "Re: ") Then
        oItem.Subject = Mid(oItem.Subject, 5)
        oItem.Save
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("F" & contor).Value = oItem.Subject
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Outlook report").Range("B" & contor).Value = oItem.Subject
    Else
        If Left(oItem.Subject, 5) = "FWD: " Then
            oItem.Subject = Mid(oItem.Subject, 6)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test 1 Mails").Range("B" & contor).Value = oItem.Subject
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Outlook report").Range("B" & contor).Value = oItem.Subject
            oItem.Save
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: So what is your question? You didn't ask one. Please read [ask]. Questions seeking debugging help ("*why isn't this code working?*") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: `1` What problem are you facing? `2` Why are you changing the Outlook subject line? Why not store it in a variable, clean it and then write to excel file?

Comment: @georgian1990, i should have asked this before i initially answered. do you have all the email info in a worksheet already? is your question a translation from another language?

Comment: are you actually asking how to extract the data from outlook and place the data into a worksheet and then process the data?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need any code to extract all the unique subject lines

1. in Outlook folder, highlight all the emails that you wish to process
2. hit ctrl-c (copy)
3. click on excel worksheet
4. hit ctrl-v (paste)
5. delete any unwanted columns
6. delete all occurences of "fw: "
7. delete all occurences of "re: "
8. select the subject column
9. do "remove duplicates" command (it is in the "data" tab ... in excel2016 anyway)

... done

Comment: This answer is off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: i agree, it is off topic, but the initial information provided is unclear.

Comment: Put the comment in the question so the OP gets automatic notification. Where there is no automatic notification you would prefix the username with @.